# Find where two (tangent) lines intersect an enclosing circle

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, drawing

I have two concentric circles and two tangent lines originating from a (single) point on the outer circle.  I want to determine where the extension of the tangent lines intersect the outer circle.  If it matters, this is in JS, drawing on a canvas.

[image]

I know the coordinates and/or values for A, R, r, Tb, Tc, [and the center of the circles, of course, which we can assume is at (0, 0)].  I need to find the coordinates of "B" and "C".

Any help/suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
B.x = 2*Tb.x - A.x
B.y = 2*Tb.y - A.y

C.x = 2*Tc.x - A.x
C.y = 2*Tc.y - A.y
```

---

Solution when `Tb, Tc` are not known (as I thought at first...):

At first we need to find tangent points `T` (`TB` and `TC`).

Small circle radius vector to tangent point is perpendicular to tangent, so scalar product of these vectors is zero - eq.[1]. And this vector's length is `r` - eq.[2], so we have equation system:

```
Tx*(Tx-Ax)+Ty*(Ty-Ay)=0       [1]
Tx^2+Ty^2 = r^2               [2]
```

Transforming it we get quadratic equation for unknown `Tx` coordinate

```
Tx^2-Tx*Ax+Ty^2-TyAy=0
r*r = Tx*Ax+TyAy
Ty = (r^2 - Tx*Ax) / Ay            [3]
Tx^2*Ay^2+(r^2 - Tx*Ax)^2 = r^2*Ay^2

Tx^2*(Ay^2+Ax^2) + Tx*(-2*r^2*Ax) + (r^4-r^2*Ay^2) = 0   [4]
```

Solving the last quadratic equation we get two (in general case) solutions for coordinates `TBx, TCx`, then calculate Y-coordinates from [3] if `Ay!=0` or from [2] otherwise.

`A-B` vector is just doubled `A-TB` vector, so

```
Bx = Ax + 2*(TBx-Ax) = 2*TBx - Ax
By = Ay + 2*(TCy-Ay) = 2*TBy - Ay
```

and similar for `C` point coordinates

Python code for reference:

```
def square_eq(a, b, c):
    Dis = b*b-4*a*c
    if Dis < 0:
        return []
    elif Dis ==0:
        return [-0.5*b/a]
    else:
        Dis = Dis**0.5
        return [0.5*(-b-Dis)/a, 0.5*(-b+Dis)/a]

def twocirctan(ax, ay, r):
    a = ay*ay+ax*ax
    if a <= r*r:
        return None
    b = -2*r*r*ax
    c = r**4-r*r*ay*ay
    sol = square_eq(a, b, c)
    if len(sol)==0:
        return None
    elif len(sol)==1:
        tbx = sol[0]
        tcx = sol[0]
        tby = (r*r - tbx*tbx)**0.5
        tcy = -tby
    else:
        tbx = sol[0]
        tcx = sol[1]
        tby = (r*r - tbx*ax) / ay
        tcy = (r*r - tcx*ax) / ay

    return [[2*tbx-ax, 2*tby-ay], [2*tcx-ax, 2*tcy-ay]]

print(twocirctan(1,0,2))
print(twocirctan(5,0,2))
print(twocirctan(3,4,2))
```

Results:

```
None
[[-3.4, 3.666060555964672], [-3.4, -3.666060555964672]]
[[-4.972848444771738, -0.520363666421197], [0.8928484447717375, -4.919636333578803]]
```

And as a JavaScript snippet:

```js
const square_eq = (a, b, c) => {
  let dis = b*b-4*a*c;
  if (dis < 0) {
    return [];
  }
  else if (dis === 0) {
    return [-0.5*b/a];
  }
  else {
    dis = dis ** 0.5;
    return [0.5*(-b-dis)/a, 0.5*(-b+dis)/a];
  }
}

const twocirctan = (ax, ay, r) => {
  const a = ay*ay+ax*ax;
  if (a <= r*r) {
    return NaN;
  }
  const b = -2*r*r*ax;
  const c = r**4-r*r*ay*ay;
  const sol = square_eq(a, b, c);
  let tbx, tcx, tby, tcy;
  if (sol.length === 0) {
    return NaN;
  }
  else if (sol.length === 1) {
    tbx = sol[0];
    tcx = sol[0];
    tby = (r*r - tbx*tbx)**0.5;
    tcy = -tby;
  }
  else {
    tbx = sol[0];
    tcx = sol[1];
    tby = (r*r - tbx*ax) / ay;
    tcy = (r*r - tcx*ax) / ay;
  }
  return [[2*tbx-ax, 2*tby-ay], [2*tcx-ax, 2*tcy-ay]];
}

console.log(twocirctan(1,0,2))
console.log(twocirctan(5,0,2))
console.log(twocirctan(3,4,2))
```

Proof picture (B,C,E,F coordinates):

[image]

Comment: I can't say I follow what you have here, so tough to tell if it's the solution I'm looking for.  However, the point that the tangent points are halfway between A->B or A->C rings true and, now that I look at it, has got to be a no-brainer.  [I could probably even prove it if I had to.]  With that now "obvious" factoid, I probably have what I need to determine coordinates "B" and "C".  Thank-you.                                                                                          If someone can follow this answer better than I and verify it's a real solution, I'm all in.

Comment: Can you solve quadratic equation [4]? I could show solution in Delphi or Python, if you read these languages

Comment: Thanks, I've learned a lot.  I think all these equations are just complicating the issue.  What's _critical_ is that the tangent between A-B is halfway between A and B.  _This_ is what "solves" it.  I know the angle between A-O and A-B, the length of the tangent line between A and Tb, and I know that the length of A-B is twice that of A-Tb.  I also know the coordinates of A, so I can "easily" calculate the coordinates of B (and, by extension, C).  [If needed, I can simply rotate the coordinate system so that the O-A line is the (positive) x-axis and, using simple trigonometry, go from there.]

Comment: `length of the tangent line between A and Tb` - no, you don't know nor this length yet neither AOB angle. As alternative - You can find rotation angle to make Y-coordinate of A' equal to small radius, get mirror point relative to OY axis, then rotate that mirror point by reverse angle. Do the same for "minus radious". Just using trig. functions like `sin,cos, atan2` instead of rather simple arithmetics.

Comment: Sorry.  Yes, I _do_ know the A-Tb length and the O-A/A-Tb angle.  (I stated as much at the beginning of the problem.)  I believe the length, A-Tb, is SQRT(R**2 - r**2) (Pythagorean Theorem), and the angle, O-A/A-Tb is ARCSIN(r/R) (similarly).  ["R" is hypotenuse, "r" intersects "Tb" at a right angle to A-Tb tangent line, forming triangle, etc.]  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ouch, I missed that Tb is known. In this case all you need is: `B.x = 2*Tb.x-A.x, B.y = 2*Tb.y-A.y`